# Designing a relationship between documents in Couchbase/CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, nosql

Learning how to build a relationship between documents in Couchbase. Maybe this question asked better with example.

Let say there are hotels and guests. Many hotels and many guests.

```
{
  "_id": "hotel1"
  "type": "hotel"
  "name": "Hilton"
  ...
}

{
  "_id": "hotel2"
  "type": "hotel"
  "name": "Hampton"
  ...
}


{
  "_id" : "guest1"
  "type": "guest"
  "name": "John"
  ...
}
{
  "_id" : "guest2"
  "type": "guest"
  "name": "Erin"
  ...
}
```

One way to build a relationship is to embed guest IDs within hotel documents but this is going to get very big over time.

The other way is that to embed hotel IDs within guest documents and create views for each hotel to list its guests. Since hotels are added over time, these views need to dynamically added whenever hotel document is created. If there are 500 hotels, they will be 500 views.

What is the cleaner way to build relationship for such data and retrieve guest data for a hotel?

Comment: I would like to point out that Couchdb and Couchbase are not the same thing, and they do not work the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am assuming Couchbase views work the same way as CouchDB views.

Put the hotel id in the guest doc. Have just one view that emits a complex key for each hotel visited by the guest. Eg

```
for (var visit in guest.hotels) {
    emit([visit.hotel_id, visit.date], guest_id);
}
```

You can then get a hotel's guest list by querying the view with

```
startkey = ['hotel1'] and endkey = ['hotel1', {}]
```

You can also get guests list between specific dates thus:

```
startkey = ['hotel1', date1] and endkey = ['hotel1', date2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the other answer posted here; however, I don't believe there is enough explanation in it for this to be educational.  If I understand your question correctly, there is a bit of a flaw in the design that the question is trying to overcome.

You importantly point out that it is not feasible to embed a list of guests within each Hotel document. Likewise, it is cumbersome, but not quite as unrealistic, to embed a list of hotels within a guest document.

What I am missing here is the fact that there are three entities needed to have a hotel stay:

1. Hotel
2. Guest
3. **Reservation**

The `Reservation` entity should contain both the Guest, the Hotel, and any relevant details specific to the particular stay. You can't put this information into either the Hotel or Guest documents, because you will eventually have objects that are too big to perform well (though admittedly it will take awhile). When in doubt, always err on the side of good performance.

Like the other answer points out, it is then quite trivial to create views that pull Guests by Hotel and Hotels by Guest.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you can create a relationship map document:

```
{
  "hotel_id": "hotel1",
  "guest_id": "guest1"
}
```

So it will store hotel/guest ids. Then you can have 2 universal views created: "ListHotelGuests" and "ListGuestHotels". You can filter, group, etc these views as per you application business logic.